# No border on UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar

Tags: ios, facebook, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I want to show my navigation bar button item but without the border of the button around it (like in the latest Facebook app built).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a "custom view" item.

Which you can create programatically via [`UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView%3a).

Comment: okay I understood that with the custom view but I totally dont understand how to get rid of it at all...

Comment: iOS convienently *wants* to draw the borders for your buttons. But using the "`customView`" method means that you are providing your own view and that the border doesn't get drawn at all.

Comment: Oh really? Thats pretty hacky :/

Comment: Not at all, actually. What Facebook and other apps tend to do is pass along a "`UIImageView`" as the parameter to the "`initWithCustomView`" method and the image gets retained.

Comment: It works. Created a UIImageView and then just added it as a customView.

Comment: Facebook doesn't use standard navigation bar. Its whole navigation bar is actually an image. The standard one is hidden. But yes this is a solution to your question.

Comment: I have another problem now. I can't assign a action to it?

Comment: if it's a separate problem from your original question, it might be smart to create a new question.